# Dissolve neighboring polygons or group neighboring polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

My task is to generate all data individually to a file that touches each other.
I first use `overlay_touches(@layer)` to get what I need, but I couldn't find a method to identify them into different group.

For example, the following pic would be 5 groups, ideally. Right now I could only think of manually select a group and `extract selected features` to each ones, which is impractical since the data would contain thousands of it. How do I do it? (Even getting the boundries of each groups is fine, since I could loop the process programmatically by PyQGIS).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Dissolve the layer with advanced parameter `keep disjoint feature separate`
checked.

2 Field calculate the `integer` field `neighborhood` as `@row_number`. Each dissolved
separate cluster of polygons will be assigned an individual id.

3 Join the neighborhood attribute to the start layer with "Join attributes by location"

4 "Split vector layer" with neighborhood as unique id field:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need, bravo!